# codeigniter misbehave: function in main controller works as expected but in helper return empty array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have following function which retrieve parent category from table then save it to an array until no one found.
this function works just fine when it be called in main controller directly from url browser, but when it be called from codeigniter helper and feeds to count() function return empty array with no element in it.

```
// in codeigniter helper:
function get_category_ancestors($catId)
{
    $ci =& get_instance();
    static $categoryAncestors = array();
    $category = $ci->a_model->get_cat_parent($catId);
    if($category->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $categoryParent = $category->row_array();
        $categoryAncestors[][$categoryParent["id"]] = $categoryParent["categoryName"];
        get_category_ancestors($categoryParent["id"]);
    }
    else
    {
        $inOrder = array_reverse($categoryAncestors);
        return $inOrder;
    }
}
```

```
// model: (for clear demonstration)
// two table: category and category_relation
public function get_cat_parent($categoryId)
{
    $this->db->select('category.*' );
    $this->db->from('category_relation');
    $this->db->where('category_relation.subCategoryId', $categoryId);
    $this->db->join('category', 'category.id=category_relation.categoryId');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}
```

```
// some other helper:(get_category_ancestors() caller)
$categoriesInOrder = get_category_ancestors($categoryId);   
$totallAncestors = count($categoriesInOrder); // =>error: Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? As far as I see, `get_category_ancestors` does not always return an array

Comment: I call it from main controller directly and works, it showed array with categories in it.

Comment: when `get_category_ancestors` does not return array? in what condition?

Comment: Have you checked your code? What makes you think that the function returns anything in case of `if($category->num_rows() > 0)`? That branch does not contain a `return` after all

Comment: I put it in main controller and call it directly from url browser, it works as expected according to my database and show categories in an array. help me please I'm desperate about it.

Comment: in case of `if($category->num_rows() > 0)` it call itself again to fine any parent category if fine any. it's weird.

Comment: "Weird"? No. A function that does not return anything does not return anything, even if you use recursive calls

Comment: how can I improve it to return something and show the issue.
is it possible something interfere with it and cause this issue. what could it be?

Comment: @Nico Haase thank's mate. you save me. as you said recursive `get_category_ancestors` need return. question is how it works directly from controller call by url browser? how?

Comment: What keeps you from debugging exactly that? Even using var_dump could help to inspect the behaviour

Comment: @Nico Haase I have used var_dump and print_r both of them return array with no element in it. what I was thinking was if it work's perfect directly so it should work in codeigniter helper as well. you helped me. thanks a lot, whole day ruined by this stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have to return `get_category_ancestors` to works.
`return get_category_ancestors($categoryParent["id"]);` not just `get_category_ancestors($categoryParent["id"]);`.